# (R) - creating a dataframe of resampled data

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
x <- c(2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 6, 5, 2, 6, 4, 5, 5, 4, 6, 1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 4, 4, 5, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 5)
```

I have resampled this data

```
resample <- sample(x, replace=TRUE)
```

Now I need to resample this data 1k times, and have each sample as a column of a matrix or dataframe. My best attempt is this:

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
    bootstrap <- matrix(resample,ncol=i)
}
```

Comment: Yes, since bootstrap methods are computationally intensive by design. Perhaps I'll even go to 10k columns. I could use bootstrap packages that would spare me having a 10k column dataframe, but since I'll have to do a presentation, doing it the "raw" way is more impressive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replicate` to do this. For instance, for 10 resamples:

```
replicate(10,sample(x,replace=TRUE))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    6    5    2    4    1    5    6    2    6     5
 [2,]    5    5    5    6    3    2    5    5    4     4
 [3,]    4    2    5    6    2    6    6    5    5     5
 [4,]    6    2    4    5    4    5    5    2    2     5
 [5,]    4    5    4    4    4    6    5    2    1     4
...
```